# Extract data between delimiters

Tags: bash

I got as result from another script a .txt with those strings ->

```
<li this="that" id="number-*">
<li me="somebody" id="number-*">
```

The * actually is a random number, and i need to get it, "number" doesn't change.

Is there a way with a Bash built-in command to do that?

Tanks

Comment: Is file format exactly as you show? No there some `</li>` tags? Or other tags?

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep -oP`

```
s='<li this="that" id="number-1234">'
echo "$s"|grep -oP 'number-\K[0-9]+'
1234
```

For older systems that don't support `grep -P` here is an awk version:

```
echo "$s" | awk -F 'number-' '{sub(/[^0-9]+/, "", $2); print $2}'
1234
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `grep`:

```
grep -oP 'number-\K\d+' inputfile
```

or

```
grep -oP '(?<=number-)\d+' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about bash builtins, but if you only want the numbers:

```
egrep -o '[0-9]+'
```

Should do it for you.

Comment: What about `<li me="some3" id="number-6">` ?

Comment: At best, the OP indicates that the value of an `id` attribute is of the form "number-[0-9]+"; it says nothing about the other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

One with `cut` and `sed`,

```
cut -d- -f 2 filename | sed 's/">//g'
```

Example:

```
$ s='<li this="that" id="number-1234">'
$ echo "$s" | cut -d- -f 2 | sed 's/">//g'
1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) built-in commands only:

```
while read; do
    [[ $REPLY =~ number-([[:digit:]]+) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done < input.txt
```

- Reads each line of the file to the built-in `$REPLY` variable, one-by-one
- Applies the regular expression `number-([[:digit:]]+)` to submatch the number you need
- If the regular expression matches, echo the submatch